# HTML files are being cached and with Visual studio publish they are still cached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, caching

I have an Angular / MVC/Web Api application

Seems like my strategy for updating JAVASCRIPT files is working with using GULP to do gulp inject with new timestamp  , so essentially

```
 javascriptFile.js?v=349003089828       // append timestamp with javascript /gulp
```

However, with a SPA in angular , I have these HTML files that get loaded based on the route and I needed to update code

I added to my `request.html`

```
<input replace="[^a-zA-Z]" with="" maxlength="4" type="text" id="CustomerNameKey" name="CustomerNameKey" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.customerNameKey" placeholder="Customer Name Key" required />
```

**This input does not display after a Visual Studio Publish to server unless people do a Control F5 !   :(  this is horrifying**

My route code is

```
    .state('request', {
          url: "/request",
          templateUrl: "app/request/request.html",
          controller: 'requestController',
          controllerAs: 'vmRequest',
          params: { user: {value: null} }
        });
```

**I'm not allowed to do this to html am i ?**

```
templateUrl: "app/request/request.html?v=234234324324",
```

If I cannot do that , what else can i do ?

Comment: If you are serving from IIS there is a way to turn off file caching, see https://superuser.com/questions/63014/how-do-i-turn-off-caching-in-iis7

Comment: however, if you are including files from a `.cshtml` or `.aspx` file, you can add a time string to force the browser to treat it as a new file, something like `@"~/path/to/file.js" + DateTime.Now`

Comment: Ok, i see , thank you